# Make a progress bar inside inner loop - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, loops

I have a project with a for loop that takes about 10 min to complete.

It's a html canvas manipulation effect, and it's just for personal use so I don't care much about the speed.

However one thing that would be really nice is if I could add a progress bar so I could know how far the program made it through the loop.

The problem is nothing I've tried seems to update until after the loop is finished.

For example consider the code below:

```
var updateDiv = document.getElementById("update"); //Get a div to write progress to

for(i=0;i<10000;i++){ 

  //super crazy code
  updateDiv.innerHTML = i;

}
```

Using this code the inner html is not written to the div until after the loop is completely done. So it doesn't work as an update feature.

I also tried `console.log(i)`, same effect.

The only javascript feature I found that will display during the loops excution is the "alert" and that pauses the loop execution as well as forces you to click a million times to get through the inner loops. So it's a no go basically.

Is there any way to display a for loops progress ?

Comment: @Wordica Trust me, it's doing a ton of work. :D I'm already using typed arrays and whatnot. It could be faster, but not by much, and 10 min is on a good run :)

Comment: Why someone delete my comment ? @zakaria acharki ? If You use arrays then mmaybe You can create 2 dimensional array and update indexes ... and then create preloader looking on arrays progress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it doesn't change is because there is no page redraw. The reason there is no page redraw, is because JavaScript works within a task queue.

As your `for` loop is currently maxing out the processor by using 100% of the available power from the OS (how much actual percent this is will vary based on browser and OS), no other tasks will be allowed to run until the for loop is complete - at which point the requested page redraw will run (also updating your graphics).

What you should really be doing is using [`requestAnimationFrame`<sup>MDN</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) for this work instead of one really large for loop. This will allow you to have all sorts of other hooks available for your animation, for monitoring, and anything else you may come up with in the future.

Comment: @ Travis J, Thank you for your fast response. Yes looking through all the given answers I understand that I have to run the code in an async fashion, and requestAnimationFrame is the most efficient way to do this. One thing I did notice is that all my code after the function (that used to run sequentially) now runs before the loop is complete, but that's how async works.

Comment: @YAHsaves - Yeah, introducing any type of async will mean refactoring other parts of the code if it is sequential. You can use promises or callbacks in order to make it still seem to be sequential though in that scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid doing it synchronously. This locks up the browser and does not allow anything else to happen. No draw cycle can happen and it looks like nothing it changing.

Try breaking it into a function that only does one step and then call it over and over through a timeout.

```js
var updateDiv = document.getElementById("update");
var i = 0;
var timeout;

function stopProcessing() {
  if(timeout) {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
  }
}


function doStep() {
  //super crazy code
  updateDiv.innerHTML = i;
  i++;
  if (i <= 100000) {
    timeout = setTimeout(doStep);
  }
}


doStep();
```

```html
<div id="update"></div>
<button onclick="stopProcessing()">Stop</button>
```

If you need this process to be as fast as possible you want `setTimeout`. If you want to synchronize with the animation buffer of canvas then use `requestAnimationFrame`

The code below shows that `setTimeout` runs quite a bit faster then `requestAnimationFrame`:

```js
var rafEl = document.getElementById('requestAnimationFrame');
var stEl = document.getElementById('setTimeout');

var rafVal = 0;
var stVal = 0;

function rafFn() {
  rafVal++;
  rafEl.textContent = rafVal;
  if (rafVal < 1000) {
    requestAnimationFrame(rafFn);
  }
}

function stFn() {
  stVal++;
  stEl.textContent = stVal;
  if (stVal < 1000) {
    setTimeout(stFn);
  }
}

rafFn();
stFn();
```

```html
    <div>requestAnimationFrame: <span id="requestAnimationFrame"></span></div>
    <div>setTimeout: <span id="setTimeout"></span></div>
```

Comment: Using a recursive setTimeout loop would be greatly improved by instead using requestAnimationFrame in all scenarios.

Comment: Last I checked `requestAnimationFrame` was slower then `setTimeout`. It is designed to provide a stable animation frame when using `canvas`. If he is not trying to draw to a canvas then `setTimeout` might be the better option.

Comment: requestAnimationFrame is commonly used with canvas because making changes to canvas requires as much performance as possible. However, that does not mean that requestAnimationFrame is merely for use with canvas. requestAnimationFrame will run after a page redraw to allow a seamless space for processing and locking the view. setTimeout can certainly be made to work, however, it should really only be used for a one time call, and not for repeated calls like this.

Comment: With setTimeout, the 50ms steps will invariably land on a page redraw and lock the UI during the work being done.

Comment: I yield. I re-read the question and realized that he was working with `canvas` so, yet, `requestAnimationFrame` is the best option. Bit I will also state that if you are just processing data and even changing `textContent` or `innerHTML` then `setTimeout`  may be the better option.

Answer (score 0):

To show the progress you could use `setInterval()` like :

```
var interval = setInterval(function() {
  updateDiv.innerHTML = i;

  if (i == max)
    clearInterval(interval);

  i++;
}, 50);
```

Code:

```js
var updateDiv = document.getElementById("update"); //Get a div to write progress to

var i = 0;
var max = 100;

var interval = setInterval(function() {
  updateDiv.innerHTML = i;

  if (i == max)
    clearInterval(interval);

  i++;
}, 50);
```

```html
<div id="update"></div>
```